# How to display page object field values in Lightning Component?

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am attempting to build a simple lightning component that will display field values from the object that it is referencing on the page.  I have applied the tutorial but cannot get the field values to display on the page.

It is not clear to me how to reference the id of the object on the page and/or whether it is necessary for the apex query or if the field value can be rendered without it.

Position__c is the reference object API with some fields:
[image]
This is my component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="positionController" access="global">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="position" type="Position__c"/>    

{!v.position.Job_Posting_One_liner__c} //I really just need to print this field value

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId"); 
        var action = component.get("c.getPositionDetails");
        action.setParams({
            "PosId": recordId
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var position = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.position", position);
        }
    });


    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex:

```
public class positionController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Position__c getPositionDetails(Id PosId) {   
    Position__c positions =  
            [SELECT Id, Job_Posting_One_liner__c FROM Position__c Where Id= :PosId limit 1 ];
    return positions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In js controller try remove quotes from this line:

```
action.setParams({
        "PosId": recordId
    });
```

so that it reads like this:

```
action.setParams({ PosId: recordId });
```